# Scaling down circles

Tags: circles, education

I've researched a lot on this topic, but I haven't been able to find anything. I was wondering if anybody knows how to scale down a circle. We are doing a project in my math class where we have to scale down a famous monument. Me and my friend are working together to scale down the Palace of Westminster (Big Ben). We know how to scale everything down, except for the actual clocks. Can you help me?

Comment: All it says is that it occupies 40sqft.

Comment: What occupies 40 sq ft., and who says so?

Answer (score 2):

All circles are similar geometrically.

If you're doing a 1/24 scale model, then Big Ben's $23$-foot diameter clock will be $23/24$ feet or $11.5"$.

Short answer:  Scale the diameter of the circle just like you would scale any other length (height, width, etc.)

Comment: Wow.. tysm, that's a lot of help (:

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the box around the circle and the circle with it:

[image]